# How to Convert NSError SignalProducer to NoError SignalProducer in ReactiveCocoa (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I have a model with a `MutableProperty<Bool>` and I have a `UIButton` (ctaTopButton) that should flip that property when it's pressed, for example, on click true becomes false and vice versa.

I have it setup this way:

```
let producer = ctaTopButton.rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside).toSignalProducer()
    |> map {value in !self.model.enabled.value}


// model.enabled <~ producer
```

The crux of my issues comes from `rac_signalForControlEvents(...).toSignalProducer()` returns a `SignalProducer<AnyObject?, NSError>` which the map converts to `SignalProducer<Bool, NSError>`

The infix operator `<~` however only works with `SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>` so I need to convert my producer somehow.

My question is, how do I demote errors?  I know there is a `promoteErrors` for converting `NoError` to `NSError`. There is also `mapError` though I can't figure out how get back an instance of `NoError` as it has no initializers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `catch()` operator for that case like:

```
let producer = ctaTopButton.rac_signalForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside).toSignalProducer()
    |> map { value in !self.model.enabled.value }
    |> catch { _ in SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>.empty }
```

Comment: a quick aside: I needed to `|> catch{ _ in SignalProducer<Bool, NoError>.empty }` It didn't like the no arguments version.

Comment: Use `flatMapError` instead of `catch` in ReactiveCocoa 3 (Swift 2), to avoid conflict with Swift 2's `catch`.